# Where are UDP_TABLE_CLASS values defined?

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, msdn

I want to call [GetExtendedUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from Iphlpapi.dll shared library, but I don't know from where to get the UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID value, so I can pass it to the function.

I don't have Windows SDK so I don't have the header files. I downloaded iphlpapi.h, iprtrmib.h, ipexport.h, iptypes.h and types.h, but couldn't find the TableClass values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all here, even the enum itself in case you can't find one of the relevant header files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366388(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, in this [file](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_hlanguage/downloads/Source/include/iprtrmib.h/) which might be outdated, I could not find the definition of UDP_TABLE_CLASS enumeration. Please don't tell me I have to download the whole SDK just to get the value of UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID.

Comment: I download Windows SDK libraries and I was able to find the UDP_TABLE_CLASS enumeration in the Iprtrmib.h file, nut I still couldn't find the UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID constant definition

Comment: In fact I searched the whole Include folder in SDK for UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID string, and I only found UDP_TABLE_CLASS enumeration, but no constant definition. I'm so confused right now ...

Comment: @user1410908: when you say you found the enumeration but not the "constant definition" I'm not sure what you mean.  Aren't the two things the same?  Anyway you can just copy-paste the enum (which defines the values, implicitly starting from zero) from the link I posted.

Comment: I don't use C++ to call the function from the shared library, so I need the value of UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID. For instance, for ulAf parameter I use 2, which is the value of AF_INET constant.

Comment: Oh .. they start from 0? So UDP_TABLE_OWNER_PID is 1